# Find matrix $A$ that act like positive definite for close vectors to $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and negative for others

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

For a given vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and angle $\alpha$, find  matrix $A_{x,\alpha}$ such than for all vectors $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ :

1- if angle between $x$ and $z$ is less than $\alpha$ then $z^TAz > 0$,

2- if angle between $x$ and $z$ is greater than $\alpha$ then $z^TAz <0$,

3- if angle between $x$ and $z$ is equal to $\alpha$ then $z^TAz =0$.

My first try was to create $A$ by using Rotation matrix, not succeeded.

My second try was to prove without lost of generality assume $A$ is symmetric then diagonalizable . So to find $A$, we only need to find a diagonal matrix like $B$. Let $\theta=$ angle between $x$ and $z$. The matrix $B=\sin (\alpha - \theta)I$ works but it's not relative to $x$.

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: find an orthogonal basis containing $x$. Now let $A$ act like $Ax=ax$ on $x$, where $a$ is positive, but like $Ay=by$ for all the other basis vectors, where $b$ is negative. This way, the matrix acts correctly on the extreme cases (angle is zero or orthogonal). Now try to find conditions for $a$ and $b$ so the matrix also acts correctly in all other cases, too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \dfrac{x}{|x|}$, then

$u \cdot z = u^T z =  |z | \cos \theta$

$ (u \cdot z)^2 = z^T z \cos^2 \theta $

So if we let $A = ( uu^T - \cos^2 \alpha I ) $

Then $z^T A z $ will be positive if $\theta \lt \alpha$, negative if $\theta \gt \alpha$, and zero if $ \theta = \alpha$.